# T-SQL Update Statment with ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2005. I would like to update fields like Order BY MatchId orders as below query. But updeted fields not order by MatchId.

```
DECLARE @counter int

SET @counter = 10008

UPDATE Matches 
SET @counter = MatchNumberCounter = @counter + 1
WHERE MatchId IN 
      (SELECT TOP (232) MatchId FROM Matches WHERE LeagueStatueId = 280 AND Week <> 1 
       ORDER BY Week, MatchDate, MatchTime)
```

Thanks already now

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to do a "quirky update". This is an undocumented technique and there are lots of conditions that need to be met for this to work. [These are discussed here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) (requires free registration)

You should be able to do something like this though.

```
;With cte As
(
SELECT TOP (232) MatchId ,
                 MatchNumberCounter, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by MatchId) as RN
FROM Matches 
WHERE LeagueStatueId = 280 AND Week <> 1 
ORDER BY Week, MatchDate, MatchTime
)
UPDATE cte SET MatchNumberCounter=RN+10008
```

Comment: thak you very much but updated fileds not order by order from select statment where clause. Clearly when selecting with above query MatchID's value coming 5,7,1 etc... i would like to update MatchNumberCounter's value by this order. MatchId = 5
MatchNumberCounter= 10009, MatchId = 7
MatchNumberCounter= 10010, MatchId = 1
MatchNumberCounter= 10011 etc..

Comment: Yes. The RowNumber is ordered by MatchId not the `order` applied for the `TOP` clause.